# How do I turn off Facebook notifications when someone likes my comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

How do I turn off notifications when someone likes something? I don't care if something is liked. It's worthless information and a waste of my time. I only care if someone responds to me or mentions me. I looked at the notification page but saw no option for turning off likes.

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=on_facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the moment. Don't know if Facebook have any plan to implement this feature in the near future.

Learn more about [how to adjust notification](https://www.facebook.com/help/390022341057202).

Here is a Chrome extension to [Hide Likes on Facebook Notifications](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-likes-on-facebook-no/kbfakkkdllpodegeoggpfcmjabodhpca). You can give it a try at your own risks.
<sup><sup>Note: I have never used this extension.</sup></sup>